# How to determine which Visual studio version used during TFS checkin

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS server 2015. I have different types of the project using different version of Visual studio: 2012/2015/2017/2019. From TFS how I can determine which version is used during check-in into TFS.
at the same time, I also want to know which MS Build version is using for TFS Build.

Comment: Why do you want to know this information?

Comment: Also, I note that the TFS client installed with Visual Studio doesn't have to correspond to the Visual Studio version - for example, Visual Studio 2008 can use Visual Studio 2010's TFS client.

Comment: And do you need to consider TFS' git services? Because then it's impossible because you can use any git client to interact with TFS' git host.

Comment: @Dai i need this information because I will implement sonar scan. Sonar scan works properly with VS 2015, But I have some very old project which is developed using VS 2012. I need to figure out which project will work properly with Sonar scan and which project not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the diagnostics panel (needs admin rights), you can see the commands TFS/Azure DevOps Server receives and the user agent passed in:

[image]

You can find it under either

```
 https://server/_oi
 https://server/tfs/_oi
```

The user agent contains the version of the TFS Client Object Model, which matches the Visual Studio version when people are doing TFS related work.

Usage of the MSSCCI provider will show up with a different Object Model Version the the Visual Studio version. As these will log the version of Team Explorer which is launched.

There is no way to detect the MsBuild version from the server logs, but the csproj file will have an indication of the .NET framework version and the MsBuild version used. It should be possible to parse out this information straight from source control.

The [ToolsVersion attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-toolset-toolsversion?view=vs-2019) should provide a nice hint.

> The `ToolsVersion` attribute is also used for project migration. For example, if you open a Visual Studio 2008 project in Visual Studio 2010, the project file is updated to include `ToolsVersion="4.0"`. If you then try to open that project in Visual Studio 2008, it doesn't recognize the upgraded `ToolsVersion` and therefore builds the project as though the attribute was still set to `3.5`.
>
> Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 use a `ToolsVersion` of `4.0`. Visual Studio 2013 uses a `ToolsVersion` of `12.0`. Visual Studio 2015 uses `ToolsVersion` `14.0`, and Visual Studio 2017 uses `ToolsVersion` `15.0`.

A second [VisualStudioVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-toolset-toolsversion?view=vs-2019#toolset-implementation) may also be present:

> Sub-toolsets become active in the presence of the `VisualStudioVersion`
> build property. This property may take one of these values:
>
> "10.0" specifies the .NET Framework 4 sub-toolset
>
> "11.0" specifies the .NET Framework 4.5 sub-toolset
>
> "12.0" specifies the .NET Framework 4.5.1 sub-toolset
>
> Sub-toolsets 10.0 and 11.0 should be used with ToolsVersion 4.0. In
> later versions, the sub-toolset version and the ToolsVersion should
> match.